# Has something changed in Eventbrite date handling?

Tags: eventbrite

I have an app that searches for events on EventBrite using the API Method event_search.

Suddenly the search using dates has stopped working and all I get back from the API is 'Error thrown while processing query' - not very helpful.

If I use 'This Month' the query works. If I use 'Next Month' I get the error with the exact same query.
Similarly 'This Week' works and 'Next Week' fails.

This despite the fact that the API documentation shows that all of these date constructs are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I verified that there were issues with the 'Next Week' and 'Next Month' named queries.  But, I was not able to reproduce the error that you are describing when doing a date range based request.

I would recommend sending your complete request URL to [Eventbrite's API support team](http://developer.eventbrite.com/contact-us/).